# Manhwa/manhua about a young female lead whose main talent is cooking

Tags: story-identification, manga

I’m looking for the name of a manhwa/manhua that has a young girl as the female lead. She is the youngest, with two older brothers. She has blue-green hair and red eyes. Her main talent is cooking.

Comment: Are there any science fiction or fantasy elements in this series? If there are, please specify them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this ***[Lady Chef Royale](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/lady-chef-royale)***...?

> Sena’s been tossed into another world, as the despised daughter of a noble family. Her little restaurant was her refuge in her last life, so she’s got some tricks up her sleeve—cooking skills! As Senianna, she’ll put her brains and fine-tuned taste buds (Korean fried chicken, anyone?) to the test so she can take back the kitchen and gain this society’s esteemed title of Chef Royale. Will her cuisine reign supreme over the empire and bring her the sweet and salty balance of power and affection?
>
> [image: Front cover of Lady Chef Royale.]

The main character is a chef with green hair, red eyes, and two brothers, and the manhwa -- which involves transmigration, and is therefore on-topic -- is available to read on [Tapas](https://tapas.io/series/lady-chef-royale/info).

Comment: That's the most cyan-looking green I've ever seen. :D